# Canvas will not clear

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have tried every clear canvas code I can find but when I click back onto the canvas, the old drawings reappear. I need it so that when you press the clear button the drawings don't come back on a new draw. I'm using paper.js if that helps

Html

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="400px" width="400px;"></canvas>
```

JS (Clearcanvas is a function from a button)

```
function clearcanvas(){

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);

    }
```

JS for the drawing function works with paper.js

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
tool.minDistance = 5;

var path;

function onMouseDown(event) {
path = new Path();
path.strokeColor = 'red';
path.strokeWidth= 3;
path.opacity="0.4";

path.add(event.point, event.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
path.add(event.point, event.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
if(event.modifiers.shift) {
    path.lastSegment.point = event.point;
    path.strokeColor = 'blue';

} else {
    path.add(event.point);
}
}    
</script>
```

Comment: `ctx.clearRect` should work. I believe that you have a bug somewhere else in your code which causes the canvas to get drawn again without you intending to do so.

Comment: You will have to provide more information/code for us to help you.

Comment: Edited with more info

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this ?

```
 canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

Comment: It clears it but when i click to draw a line, everything comes back again